Why was getting Indians to stop working for the British government never targeted during the freedom struggle?
[Edit] I have simplified the question greatly
The British could not have maintained control over India if not for significant indigenous support. There was a significant percentage of Indians that worked for the British govt, were in the British Indian army.
Why was getting Indians to stop working for the British government never targeted during the freedom struggle?

You have two distinct questions here. The SE format works best with a single question per thread. I would, therefore, suggest that you split this into two separate (if related) questions in their own threads.

@SteveBird The overall question I have is why were collaborators accepted during and in post colonial India?

@avinash - please edit the question to clarify.  History shows that if people need to read the comments to understand the question they'll vote to close.

I've had friends from various parts of India who said that the various Indian kingdoms had been endlessly warring with each other, and the British made that stop. And, still, it's not that "India" is a homogeneous country, since different states have different languages and different customs (apart from the imposed common English...)

The "own countrymen" is a sentiment of British making. While there was a clear kinship between different states of South Asia, before the British conquest, it hadn't really been like the modern concept of statehood and nation we see today. A Punjabi was a Punjabi, a Gujarati was a Gujarati, a Kashmiri was a Kashmiri etc. British conquest itself was done by South Asian soldiers, British never had a big military or colonist presence there. India was not a nation-state before British. It is a union of many nations even today.

Try asking why some Germans and some German states collaborated with Napoleon, or why some Europeans collaborated with the USSR or even the Nazis. A common location or a common language or a common ethnicity do not unanimity of purpose make. (It doesn't even happen within families all the time!)

Some of the related answers should be quite enlightening, for example this one about collaboration among the princes and this one about the regional loyalties of soldiers.

I hope you understand that "Punishment for collaborators with Germany" and the "Truth and Reconciliation Commission" were two extremely different things. In fact the T&RC was set up specifically so that South Africa didn't go down the "punishment for collaborators" route.

@DJClayworth completely agree. But between those 2 ends of the spectrum, from what I am aware of, India did not really even have a process to "reconcile". I was not advocating for the extrajudicial "punishment for collaboration" approach. What I am trying to get at is, was there even some sort of commission/study to understand what went wrong and how to make sure it never happens again

@avinash.  Please move all your comments into the question. Revise the question to address the comments.  RIght now people have to read a question and a dozen comments to understand the question and start on research.  That makes it almost certain that your question will not get an answer.

What evidence is there that "getting Indians to stop working for the British government [was] never targeted during the freedom struggle?" And if that's the question, why is the headline something completely different?

@BrianZ I grew up studying Indian history and do not remember reading about such a campaign

@avinash While I've not studied Indian history in any depth I know there was a Sepoy Mutiny, and I know about the Quit India movement. Why don't those count?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)


Question:
Was there significant Indian support for British rule in India?

Short Answer:
Yes, over time certain important segments of India's population supported and enabled British rule for diverse reasons.
Answer:
Throughout the period of British rule in India, the question of support or opposition to colonial domination was complex and multifaceted. While the Indian independence movement, led by figures such as Mahatma Gandhi, Jawaharlal Nehru, and Subhas Chandra Bose, is widely celebrated for its resistance to British rule, it is also important to recognize that certain sections of Indian society, at various times, supported or collaborated with the British. This support was motivated by diverse factors, ranging from personal gain and political pragmatism to ideological beliefs about modernization and governance. Understanding this phenomenon requires examining the role of Indian elites, local rulers, and ordinary citizens within the British colonial structure.
A significant base of support for British rule came from the Indian princes who ruled over the princely states. At the height of British control, nearly one-third of the Indian subcontinent was governed by more than 500 princely states, which were semi-autonomous under British suzerainty. The British allowed these rulers a degree of internal independence in exchange for loyalty and acceptance of British oversight in matters of foreign policy and defense.
For many of these princes, British rule offered a sense of security. They were able to maintain their power, wealth, and privileges, which may have been more precarious in a fragmented post-Mughal political landscape. The British often intervened to protect these rulers from internal threats and revolts, thus ensuring a stable system of governance. Many Indian princes saw their relationship with the British as mutually beneficial, as the British provided the military and administrative structure necessary to maintain their own authority.
In addition to the princely states, many members of the Indian landed gentry and administrative classes found reasons to support British rule. Large landowners, particularly zamindars in regions like Bengal and Bihar, benefited from British economic policies that reinforced their control over vast estates. The British introduced the Permanent Settlement in Bengal in 1793, which formalized the power of zamindars and ensured their collaboration in collecting revenue for the British government. These landowners, in turn, saw their political and economic interests closely aligned with the continuation of British rule.
British policies also enabled a class of Western-educated Indians to rise within the colonial administrative apparatus. The Indian Civil Service (ICS) and other branches of the colonial bureaucracy were open to educated Indians, particularly after the introduction of competitive examinations in the 19th century.  Satyendranath Tagore was the first Indian who passed the Indian Civil Service Examination in June 1863. Many Indians, often from elite or upper-caste backgrounds, pursued careers within this system, seeing British rule as a path toward social mobility, professional success, and access to modern education. These individuals, while sometimes critical of specific policies, often believed that British governance brought modernization and stability to India.

Thanks, I think this answer makes the most sense, The British Empire in India would not have lasted as long as it did if not for aligned Indian interests.

It should be noted than independence (in India and even in less developed colonies) doesn't mean destruction of the administration set by imperial powers, but replacing the imperial control of that administration by local control, and put that administration to work in the sole interest of the former colony and not the colonial power.

No significant groups among the independence activists wanted the administration of India to collapse. They wanted the police, post/telegraph/telephone and railway systems to keep on working. The people who worked in those systems also wanted to keep their jobs and incomes.
Through the inter-war decades, political pressure had been having worthwhile effects, with regional elections and administrations, the ending of monopolies, and so on. The British were gradually conceding power - not as quickly as the activists wanted, but there was progress.
This was messed up in September 1939, when the Viceroy, Lord Linlithgow, declared war on Germany all by himself, without consulting Indian politicians. He did have the legal right to do that, but it showed that India was not his highest priority. He also rejected the INC's request for a promise that India would have the chance to determine its own future after the war. That significantly devalued British promises and intentions.
It nonetheless took until August 1942, after the failure of the Cripps Mission, for widespread civil disobedience to start. The Quit India movement was not supported by the Muslim League, who wanted a separate Pakistan, the main Hindu nationalist party of the time   and many Indians in national organisations, as well as businesses profiting from wartime spending.

do you have any reference to "None of the independence activists wanted the administration of India to collapse."? why would they not want that? It would have hastened the British departure.

@avinash: None of the major pro-independence groups were anarchists. They didn't want the princely states to go back to having wars with each other, or to have the transport and communication systems to stop working, leading to starvation in some places and economic downturn. They wanted India to be run in the interests of Indians, rather than the British, and the easiest way to do that was to have the British leave peacefully.

If that wasn't what they wanted, why are so many aspects of India still recognisably similar to how they were at independence? Indian governments have had plenty of time to make changes.

The fundamental premise of the question is counterfactual. The 1857 rebellion began with a mutiny--that is, an organized refusal of Indians to cooperate with British rule. The entire essence of the Quit India movement was to call for total non-cooperation with British authorities. So the answer to the question is that opponents of British rule, and eventually supporters of independence, absolutely did work to encourage their fellow Indians not to support British rule.

One of the reasons the 1857 rebellion failed was that it was not as widely supported. It was mostly confined to the north west region. In fact it is well documented that it was Indian sepoys of varying regiments that helped the British suppress the rebellion.
The Quit India movement, while having broader support, was also opposed by various sections of society.
But I think you are missing the broader point I am trying to make which is that a large percentage of Indians collaborated with, supported and benefited from British rule

@acinash That  comment raises two  separate, potentially answerable historical questions, both of which are completely different from the one you asked.
